# Remove extra horizontal white space on mobile (css)

Tags: html, css

I having an issue with extra blank horizontal white space being added when I'm on mobile.  It is hidden at first, but if i scroll right or swipe right it becomes visible.

I can't seem to pinpoint exactly where in my code it is forcing this width to go beyond 100%. I have my mobile `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">` correct and in my `head` tag.

Here is the website in question: [wpdev.mosaic.buzz/wordpress12](http://wpdev.mosaic.buzz/wordpress12).

Use dev tools and simulate a mobile browser and go below 1000px.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Some of your input fields in the form at the bottom of the page have the attribute `size="100%"` - if you remove that attribute and instead set a style attribute (like `<input type="text" style="width:100%">` , you should be back in business.

The `size` attribute is meant to contain the width (in characters) of an input. So `size="50"` would be 50 characters wide. But `size="100%"` will give you... weirdness.

Comment: Thanks for help. That fixed it down to about 600px. I even completely removed the "size" inline style and it is still giving me lots of extra white space.  Weird. I removed the entire form itself and the white space remains.